# Redux: Reducer not mutating state in first attempt

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am working on a Table in React based application using typescript. I am implementing search functionality for the table. There is a huge amount of data that can be displayed inside table so I am performing search, sorting, pagination all at back end.

I have a component for the table which receives data as props from a parent component. I am using react with redux and using sagas, I get the data from back end. I am using redux state to provide data to component. I am using reducers to mutate the state.

The problem I am facing is that when I reload the data, I get the data and using reducer I mutate the state but that is not being displayed at frontend. But when I try second time, it displays the data.

My code for reducer is below.

```
const dataEnteries: Reducer<any> = (
    state = {},
    { type, detail, pagination }: DataResponse
) => {
    switch (type) {
        case actionTypes.DATA_LOAD_RESPONSE:
            if (!detail) {
                return {};
            }
            const data: any[] = [];
            const tableData: any[] = [];
            detail.forEach((o) => {
                tableData.push(o.dataDetail);
                Data.push(o)
            })
            const resultMap = new Map()
            resultMap["data"] = data;
            resultMap["tableData"] = tableData;
            resultMap["pagination"] = pagination;
            return resultMap;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

here is my map state to props function

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ data }: { data: DataState }): DataProps => ({
    data: data.dataEnteries
});
```

dataEnteries is the innermost property

I am unable to figure out what is going wrong in my case as at second time, things works rightly.

Comment: What is the shape of your store? If auditEnteries is your root reducer then there isnt going to be a dataEnteries property in the store

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use spread operator on return.

`return ...resultMap`

When you update a prop inside an object the state didn't recognise the change then the render will not be called to refresh the component.

Try this, if not work let me know.

For further referente check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: it is not working as I am using type script, ... before resultMap is returning error,  error TS1109: Expression expected.